Error: Assertion Failed: expected container not to be destroyed
Reproduction
Probably related to https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5570
test('test', async function (assert) {
  assert.dom('item').exists({ count: 2 });

  await click('.menu');
  await click('.delete');
  await settled();

  assert.dom('item').exists({ count: 1 });
});

Description
Both assertion are passing when i put debugger;  or await pauseTest() and then restore i don't seem to have any issues. I also tried to use await settled(); but still having same issues
"ember-cli": "~3.8.3"
"ember-data": "~3.8.3"

